# Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404) why?

Tags: css, html, caching, laravel-4

So my appcache is giving this error:

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23uv5eo&s=8#.VGUTs_mG9Zw

My file structure looks like this:

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2yw73oi&s=8#.VGUUXvmG9Zw

My HTML tag:

```
<html manifest="manifest.appcache" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**Manifest.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/images/header/buttonIn.png
/images/header/buttonOut.png

NETWORK:
*
```

- Why am i getting error i'm getting?
- Can someone please for once and for all explain to me how to make a file with a .appcache extension? so much unclarity about this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you run an apache server. Try adding `AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache` to your .htaccess file.

More info about this at [this blog post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)